# Quadrature of square's diagonal

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

I came up with this problem during shortening my road to an university on a car park.

We will build a sequence of geometrical figures. As sequence's first element let's consider a square with a side equal to $1$. Each $n+1$ element of a sequence is created from $n$-th element by dividing each side facing "up" or "right" on half and turning each "up-right" corner into "down-left" (check the image).

[image: 4 first elements]

We know that each element has a cuircuit equal to $4$. But the field is constantly decreasing and it's easy to spot that the lower bound of the field is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

The question is: can we say that the limit of these figueres is equal to rectangular triangle (can we say about a limit of figures at all)?

If yes, then if we build a numerical sequence $a_k = $ cuircuit of $k$-th figure, we will get a $a_k = 4, \forall k \in \mathbb{R} $, but $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_k = 2+\sqrt2$ ?

Comment: A relevant [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $a_k=4\implies \lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=4$.

You just shown that the limit of the length is not the length of the limit. (No theorem states this.)

Comment: But if  consider e.g. Euclidean metric we have $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n : d(x,y_n) < \epsilon$, where $x$- square diagonal, $y_n$- $n$-th figure "diagonal" curve (to ommit domain problems let's rotate the figures $45^{\circ}$). In Euclidean metric limit is equal to diagonal? Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: I meant $L_2$ metric.

Comment: Analogically $1/n$ is never equal to $0$ but it convergences to it. As I said it appears that in $L_2$ the $y_n$ has a limit and it is $x$ (as the condition of convergence is met).

Comment: @vermator: I changed my answer.